# Query to Read records from three TABLES

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query to read records from three TABLES say TABLE A,TABLE B,TABLE C. Each table has ID and creationdatetime column as common between them.

I can insert data from front end

1. either in TABLE A
2. or in TABLE B
3. or in TABLE C
4. or TABLE A and TABLE B
5. or TABLE B and TABLE C
6. or TABLE C and TABLE A
7. or TABLE A and TABLE B and TABLE C.

And also data returned from the query should be sorted in descending order based on creationdatetime column of the records and also there should not be any duplicates.

Please refer:

```
TABLE A: ID   creationdatetime 

TABLE B: ID   creationdatetime

TABLE C: ID   creationdatetime
```

**Scenario:-1**

```
TABLEA
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00

TABLEB
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00

TABLEC
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00
```

**Scenario:-2**

```
TABLEA
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00

TABLEB (No Data)
ID    Creationdatetime

TABLEC
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00
```

**Scenario:-3**

```
TABLEA
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00

TABLEB (No Data)
ID    Creationdatetime

TABLEC (No DATA)
ID    Creationdatetime
```

**Scenario:-4**

```
TABLEA
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 11.00

TABLEB
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 12.00

TABLEC
ID    Creationdatetime
1     2014-05-28 13.00
```

Just to add from the four scenario's Which I have mentioned above .I expect a query which should return:

Scenario:-1,Scenario:-2,Scenario:-3= one record and 
Scenario:-4= 3 records

This is a sample code which I am trying to join two tables:

```
select * from TABLEA, TABLEB
where TABLEA.ID=9205920588298715136
group by TABLEB.creationdatetime
order by TABLEB.creationdatetime desc
```

Comment: Yes, and what code have you tried in your own effort to solve this problem? This is fairly rudimentary in any sql dialect.

Comment: how about providing some of your previous attempts? People are going to be less likely to want to help if you haven't proved you are trying to help yourself

Comment: beat me to it @J.Steen hehe

Comment: This is a sample code which i am trying two join two tables:- i.e TABLE A and TABLE B.
select  *

from TABLEA,TABLEB 
where  TABLEA.ID=9205920588298715136
group by TABLEB.creationdatetime
order by TABLEB.creationdatetime desc

Comment: But the above query returns zero records when i have records only in table A but not in TABLE B

Comment: Please help me in resolving this one and let me know if you need more inputs from me.

Comment: I have tried using UNION ALL but it is not working. I need to eliminate duplicates based on creation date time.I can;t use distinct keyword because i am not sure to which table creationdatetime column i need to refer

Comment: Please throw some light

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.columna,
       table2.columnb,
       table3.columnc

from table1

join table2
    on table1.creationdatetime = table2.creationdatetime 

join table3
    on table3.creationdatetime = table2.creationdatetime 


ORDER BY creationdatetime DESC
```

You haven't given me enough info on table structure or what data could be the same to cause duplicates... So I cannot answer that bit.

EDIT: I can't comment so I'll have to post it here, to get distinct data using joins you could use the group by and distinct keywords. (If you didn't mind which row it returned)

Comment: Just to add following are the scenario's I need to write a query for this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use union in stead of joins.
Union between all tables will give you distinct data of all three tables.

```
Select * from Table1
Union
Select * from Table2
Union
Select * from Table3
```

Considering all tables have similar table structure.

Or If you want all the columns of Tables, you can use full outer join between them. It will give you all the rows as per your requirement.

```
Select * from Table1 A
full outer join table2 B on A.Id = B.Id
Full outer join Table3 C on A.Id = C.Id
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Just want to add some thing here .I am using H2 database looks like H2 wont support Union or full outer join.Once again Thanks a lot

Comment: @manzur, I found an article, which says union works in H2 database also. The URL is http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select Please check this. Though could not found Full outer join, but check if http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#table_expression URL helps

Comment: Thanks a million Roopesh

Comment: Just to addd from the four scenario's I have mentioned above .I expect a query which should return.

Comment: Scenario:-1,Scenario:-2,Scenario:-3= one record and Scenario:-4=3 records

Comment: Hi,I think you are not understanding mine question.Question is "How to link three table records when data is inserted in either of the tables say data may be there in TABLE A or TABLE B or TABLE C.It is not mandatory that data will be present in all three tables and I have foreign key in common

Comment: Hi, I am extremely sorry.Please give me access to post the question.